# Is there any way to map user info with their tweets without too many fetching?

Tags: swift, twitter

I am now trying to create a simple Twitter client using SwiftUI, and currently at the point where I try to fetch my timeline.

Reading the official Twitter API v2 document, there is a way to fetch timeline, but it only offers tweet ID, text, created_at, and author Id.

so I tried to fetch author info using the author Id in loop, which causes too many fetching data and many of them are redundant because a single user tweet many times.

This way makes my account easily reach the api limit, but I am struggling to find better ways.

I am not an enginner and write codes just for fun, so I am not really familiar with techniques enginners should know... I would appreciate if you give me even a hint.

Here is my code below.

```
 func getStream(client: TwitterAPIClient, id: String) async throws {
        let response = await client.v2.timeline.getUserReverseChronological(.init(
            id: id,
            expansions: TwitterTweetExpansionsV2.all, maxResults: 20,
            mediaFields: TwitterMediaFieldsV2.all,
            tweetFields: TwitterTweetFieldsV2.all.subtracting([.promotedMetrics, .nonPublicMetrics, .organicMetrics]),
            userFields: TwitterUserFieldsV2.all)
        )
            .responseDecodable(type: TwitterDataResponseV2<
                               [TwitterTimelineV2],
                               TwitterTimelineV2.Include,
                               TwitterTimelineV2.Meta>.self)

        if let error = response.error {
            print(error)
            throw error
        } else {
            print(response.success!)
        }
        
        print(response)
        
        let timeline = try response.map { $0.data }.result.get()
        
        for tweet in timeline {
            let response = try await getUserInfo(client: client, id: tweet.authorId).result.get()
            print(response)
        }
    }
```

Note: TwitterAPIClinet is a client of a third party library.

Comment: You could store fetched account info in a cache and then check the cache first before requesting the account information. You could use a dictionary for this with the account id as the key.

Comment: Which third party client library is this? You already have the fields and expansions specified in the initial API call so you should have more than just the id and text in the response. What’s the response you’re getting?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I looked into the documents and turned out that I get to fetch more than id and text in the response just like Andy said. What a mistake, anyway, I can code with this in more natural way. Thank you, Andy, and Sotiris and Joakim, too

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetching user data for each individual tweet, you could first loop the `timeline` array and store each user **once** in a dictionary. Then, you can request the user info based on that dictionary.

```
let timeline = try response.map { $0.data }.result.get()
var usersDictionary = [String : Bool]()

for tweet in timeline {
    usersDictionary[tweet.authorId] = true
}

for authorId in usersDictionary.keys {
    let response = try await getUserInfo(client: client, id: authorId).result.get()
    print(response)
}
```